# Physical interpretation of bra and ket notation mean

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation

I have just started learning quantum computing.

The pure state
|0>

has vector
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0 
\end{bmatrix}

Now what does 1 and 0 indicate about the quantum state ?

Answer (score 1):

The $1$ and $0$ show that the state is a linear combination of the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, and it is in fact the state

$$1 \times |0\rangle + 0 \times |1\rangle$$

which, not surprisingly, is equal to $|0\rangle$. A measurement of a system in state $|0\rangle$ will always give the result $0$, and will never give the result $1$.

In general, the vector

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta 
\end{bmatrix}$$

(where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers) represents the state

$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$$

As long as we have normalised the vector so that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$ then the probability that a measurement of a system in state $|\psi\rangle$ will give the result $0$ is $|\alpha|^2$, and the probability that it will give the result $1$ is $|\beta|^2$.